# Chrome拡張機能を公開するにあたって概要の説明欄で同じテキストが２つ表示される

Tags: chrome-extension

拡張機能を公開したいのですが、概要の説明欄が変な挙動を起こします。
画像のように同じテキストが２つ表示されます。（テキストはGoole Keepから拝借しました）
これを回避するにはどうすればいいですか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manifest.jsonにdescriptionを書いていない場合に、同じ文章が挿入されるようです。

```
"description":"-説明-"
```

を書くことで回避できました。